# iPad home screen shortcut website returns to homepage after visiting another app - jQuery Mobile site

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, mobile

I have an issue where a website accessed via iPad homepage shortcut always returns to the originally bookmarked page if you go out of it, into another app, then back.

This is different to if you access the website using safari / chrome, in these cases the browser loads the page the user was on when they tabbed out of the app.

The site is made with jQuery Mobile and Joomla.

Here's the workflow:

1. Visit site using Safari
2. Login
3. Set the page as a home screen shortcut
4. Go to the website via the short cut
5. Login
6. Press home button, go into another app
7. Go back to the shot cut website

At this stage the page goes white briefly then returns to the app home page instead of staying on the page you were on when you left.

Any thoughts on what may cause this?